# How do I send an email to a list of people without them seeing the other email addresses?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

I have a group of friends and family that I would like to send an email to, but I don't want everyone to see everyone's email address at the top.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking to use is the "Blind Carbon Copy" or Bcc for short option.  Here's how you use it:

## Outlook.com

1. Create a new message by selection `+ New`:

   [image]
2. Select the `Bcc` button:

   [image]
3. Enter any contacts into the newly created box (directly below the `Bcc` and **not** the `To`):

   [image]

## Gmail

1. Create a new message by selecting `Compose`:

   [image]
2. Select the `Bcc` button:

   [image]
3. A new line will appear where you can add the recipients:

   [image]